# Conversion of slice to array pointer

Tags: arrays, go, pointers, type-conversion, slice

As mentioned in [Spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions), Converting a slice to an array pointer yields a pointer to the underlying array of the slice.

```
s := make([]byte, 2, 4)
s0 := (*[0]byte)(s)      // s0 != nil
```

---

But compiler gives error: `cannot convert s (variable of type []byte) to *[0]byte`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This conversion was added to the language in [Go 1.17](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17).

> ### Changes to the language
>
> Go 1.17 includes three small enhancements to the language.
>
> - [Conversions from slice to array pointer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer): An expression `s` of type `[]T` may now be converted to array pointer type `*[N]T`. If `a` is the result of such a conversion, then corresponding indices that are in range refer to the same underlying elements: `&a[i] == &s[i] for 0 <= i < N`. The conversion panics if `len(s)` is less than `N`.
> - [...]

This means you need Go 1.17 or newer to use such conversion. It works well on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1MG7zgcg2pw) (currently the playground uses the latest Go 1.19).

Comment: I was testing with go 1.16.9